# Generating 3D surface between 2 linestrings using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, 3d

I'm trying to create a surface with a slope between 2 circles, i.e. one large external circle with a Z equal to 300 (m) and another one inside, smaller and  with a Z equal to 200 (m).  I should obtain a polygonal surface like the section of a cone standing upside down.  The Polygon is generated but when a query the min and max Z value of it I obtain the same value.  Here is my code :

`SELECT e.id,
    st_Zmin(e.geom) AS max_alti,
    st_Zmin(i.geom) AS min_alti,
    st_Zmin(st_buildarea(st_collect(e.geom, i.geom))),
    st_Zmax(st_buildarea(st_collect(e.geom, i.geom))),
    st_buildarea(st_collect(e.geom, i.geom)))::geometry(PolygonZ,31370) AS geom
   FROM external_circle e
     LEFT JOIN internal_circle i ON e.id = i.id;`

```
id  max_alti    min_alti    st_Zmin st_Zmax geom
1   332         232         332.0   332.0   -
2   346         246         346.0   346.0.  -
```

It seems that what I obtain is a horizontal donut.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong until I'm strong in 3D, but I'd go in the direction http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extrude.html and http://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DDifference.html

Comment: I'm not sure, ST_extrude seems to extrude a 2D surface along the Z axis to create a volume, while I want to create a curved surface inclined in space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D support in PostGIS has come a long way, but it's functionality should not be confused with that of e.g. CAD software; the creation and handling of *3D objects in the stricter sense* is not what PostGIS is intended for, it won't just simply create 3D meshes from arbitrary input geometries.

With that in mind, give the docs on [3D supporting functions](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_3D_Functions) & [polyhedral surface supporting functions](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_PS_GeometryFunctions) a good read maybe, and note that you will likely need to have *[SFCGAL](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal)* activated.

And then you would need to use PostGIS' two main geometric entry points into 3D:

- the *POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z*, for which you would need to provide **each
  and every face of a 3D object** to construct by hand
- a TIN mesh from *Points* with e.g. `ST_DelaunyTriangles`. This would
  come close to creating 3D objects in the stricter sense, but requires
  geometries to be present as points and some care to get the right
  output

---

As to why you are not getting different Z values: when provided a *MultiPolygon* as in your case (via `ST_Collect`), `ST_BuildArea` will implicitly extract each parts' boundary and treats them as individual rings where possible, with the outer rings' Z value assigned to the resulting *Polygon*. Try the same with `ST_Polygonize` (this is an aggregate function by itself, no need for `ST_Collect`) and you would get the correct Z value.

**Note that this would still be no 3D surface or solid, but just a collection of 2 *Polygons* with Z values!**

Comment: Thank you for that clear answer, @ThingumaBob.  It's rather disappointing, but I suspected that I was approaching some postgis limits.   FYI, SFCGAL is installed and the query on Zmin/max had no other purpose than to check my result, my goal was to create this surface.  I may try the POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z .