# Convert a LineString Z into a PolyhedralSurface in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sfcgal, polyhedralsurface

Follow up on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447174/polygonize-a-vertical-plane-defined-by-a-multilinestring-z-in-postgis), *if possible*, how can I convert a geometry from a closed `MULTILINESTRING Z` into a `POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z` in PostGIS 3.3+?

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358361/converting-polyhedralsurface-to-multilinestring-or-polygon) is the perfect opposite.

Sample data:

```sql
SELECT (ST_GeomFromText(
 'MULTILINESTRING Z ((
    0 1 5,
    0 1 6,
    7 2 6,
    7 2 2,
    8 3 2,
    8 3 5,
    0 1 5
  ))'
))
```

--> expected output:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_<something>(ST_GeomFromText(
 'MULTILINESTRING Z ((
    0 1 5,
    0 1 6,
    7 2 6,
    7 2 2,
    8 3 2,
    8 3 5,
    0 1 5
  ))'
)));
------------------------
'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
    0 1 5,
    0 1 6,
    7 2 6,
    7 2 2,
    8 3 2,
    8 3 5,
    0 1 5
)))'
(1 row)
```

I've never found any function for "building" such polyhedral surfaces in the PostGIS documentation, every example there is build from scratch, by hand. Even [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311507/65370), it's stated it's hand-made.

Some refs:

- [15.10. PostGIS Polyhedral Surface Support Functions](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_PS_GeometryFunctions)
- [15.8. PostGIS Functions that support 3D](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_3D_Functions)